# JqGrid - Set Default Operand For a Column

Tags: jqgrid

Is it possible to set a default search operand for a single column? The column is called "Severity" and has default value of 4. I would like to display "le" and by default filter values that are less or equal to this value.

Here is a snippet from the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#grid').jqGrid({
            url:'logging.ajax',
            datatype: 'json',
            colModel:[
                {name:'Code', index:'Code', width:100, sorttype:'int', searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','cn','ne','nc','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','bn','in','ni','ew','en']}},
                {name:'Severity', index:'Severity', width:100, sorttype:'int', searchoptions:{defaultValue: 4, sopt:['eq','cn','ne','nc','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','bn','in','ni','ew','en']}},
                {name:'Log', index:'Log', align: 'left', width:200, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','cn','ne','nc','bw','bn','in','ni','ew','en']}},
            {name:'ID', index:'ID', width: 100, sorttype:'int', key: true, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','cn','ne','nc','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','bn','in','ni','ew','en']}}
            ],
            rowNum: 500,
            rowList: [100,200,500,1000],
            styleUI : 'Bootstrap',
            gridview: true,
            pager: '#gridpagernav',
            sortname: 'ID',
            loadonce: false,
            viewrecords: true,
            cellEdit: false,
            sortorder: 'desc',
            multiSort: true,
            ExpandColClick: true,
            forceFit: true,
            editurl:'logging.ajax',
            autowidth: true,
            shrinkToFit: false,
            height: Math.max(200, $(window).height()-400)
        }).navGrid('#gridpagernav',
            {
            edit: false,
            add: false,
                del: false,
            refresh: true,
            search: true,
            recreateForm: true
            }, //options
            {
            }, // edit options
            {
            }, // add options
            {
            }, // del options
            {
            closeAfterSearch: true,
            multipleSearch: true,
            multipleGroup: true,
            showQuery: false,
            } // search options
        ).filterToolbar({stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: 'cn', ignoreCase: true, searchOperators: true});
```

I commonly use the following trick to display different operand in the search toolbar. It works fine for "cn".

```
$('.soptclass[colname=\"Severity\"]').attr('soper', 'le')
$('.soptclass[colname=\"Severity\"]').html('<=')
$('.soptclass[colname=\"Log\"]').attr('soper', 'cn')
$('.soptclass[colname=\"Log\"]').html('~')
```

When I add the following line of code, it automatically uses the right filtering on load and when I play around with other columns, it always uses the correct filter.

```
postData: { filters:JSON.stringify({'rules': [{'field':'Severity', 'op':'le', 'data':'4'}]}) },
```

However, when I press refresh button, filtering is reset to "eq".

What I would like to achieve is that either "le" on the column "Severity" is always enforced or to somehow fix the refresh button so it modifies filter's "op".

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

By default first option in sopt array is defaul. To do what you want set it like this

```
        colModel:[
            ... 
            {name:'Severity', index:'Severity', width:100, sorttype:'int', searchoptions:{defaultValue: 4, sopt:['le','eq','cn','ne','nc','lt','gt','ge','bw','bn','in','ni','ew','en']}},

             ...
        ],
```

and you can delete the code which change the the 'le' to default one.

Comment: That doesn't work, when I press refresh button. It still uses "eq".

Comment: The problem appear only when defaultValue is used in searchoptions. In all other cases it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding custom navigation button that replaces refresh button. Solution is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#grid').jqGrid({
        url:'logging.ajax',
        datatype: 'json',
        postData: { filters:JSON.stringify({'rules': [{'field':'Severity', 'op':'le', 'data':'4'}]}) },
        colModel:[
            {name:'Code', index:'Code', width:100, sorttype:'int', searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','cn','ne','nc','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','bn','in','ni','ew','en']}},
            {name:'Severity', index:'Severity', width:100, sorttype:'int', searchoptions:{defaultValue: 4, sopt:['eq','cn','ne','nc','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','bn','in','ni','ew','en']}},
            {name:'Log', index:'Log', align: 'left', width:200, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','cn','ne','nc','bw','bn','in','ni','ew','en']}},
        {name:'ID', index:'ID', width: 100, sorttype:'int', key: true, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','cn','ne','nc','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','bn','in','ni','ew','en']}}
        ],
        rowNum: 500,
        rowList: [100,200,500,1000],
        styleUI : 'Bootstrap',
        gridview: true,
        pager: '#gridpagernav',
        sortname: 'ID',
        loadonce: false,
        viewrecords: true,
        cellEdit: false,
        sortorder: 'desc',
        multiSort: true,
        ExpandColClick: true,
        forceFit: true,
        editurl:'logging.ajax',
        autowidth: true,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        height: Math.max(200, $(window).height()-400)
    }).navGrid('#gridpagernav',
        {
        edit: false,
        add: false,
        del: false,
        refresh: false,
        search: true,
        recreateForm: true
        }, //options
        {
        }, // edit options
        {
        }, // add options
        {
        }, // del options
        {
        closeAfterSearch: true,
        multipleSearch: true,
        multipleGroup: true,
        showQuery: false,
        } // search options
    ).filterToolbar({stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: 'cn', ignoreCase: true, searchOperators: true});
```

I have added postData line and changed "refresh" from true to false, which removes the native refresh button. I have added following new code:

```
    $('#grid').navButtonAdd('#gridpagernav',{
        caption: '',
        buttonicon: 'glyphicon-refresh',
        onClickButton: function() {
        var postData = $('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam','postData');
        if ((postData) && (postData.filters)) {
            var filters = JSON.parse(postData.filters);
            if (filters.rules) {
                var rowsCount = filters.rules.length;
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
                    if (filters.rules[i].field) {
                        $('#gs_' + filters.rules[i].field).val('');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        $('.soptclass[colname=\"Severity\"]').attr('soper', 'le')
        $('.soptclass[colname=\"Severity\"]').html('<=')
        $('#gs_Severity').val('4');
        $('#grid').setGridParam({ postData: { filters:JSON.stringify({'rules': [{'field':'Severity', 'op':'le', 'data':'4'}]}) } });
            $('#grid').trigger('reloadGrid');
        },
    });
```

This creates a new navigation button and places it as the last button. As I am using bootstrap UI, I have to use glyphicon icons. When user presses the button, it removes any filled out values in the top filtering/search toolbar and puts back Severity value 4 and operand. It sets the filtering back and triggers reloadGrid.

I am also still using this code, so that it changes visually operand at the grid load:

```
$('.soptclass[colname=\"Severity\"]').attr('soper', 'le')
$('.soptclass[colname=\"Severity\"]').html('<=')
```

Comment: It is important to know version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: Version is: jqGrid  5.3.2.

Comment: This version is very old, so it can be a possible to have this problem.

Comment: It is. I have requested an upgrade.